# "Object does not match target type" error occurs in C# web application while binding GridView control with List having different types

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, factory

For `C#` web application, I am populating a `List` (using Factory pattern) with different types of objects i.e. `List<IAnimal>` stores objects of type Cat or Dog. While binding this List to `GridView` control, "Object does not match target type" exception occurs. Whereas the same List binds successfully with `ListView` control. Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Code snippet is mentioned here for your reference:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdAnimals.DataSource = CreateAnimalList();
    grdAnimals.DataBind();

}

private List<IAnimal> CreateAnimalList()
{
    List<IAnimal> objAnimals = new List<IAnimal>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            IAnimal objCat = new Cat();
            objCat.Name = "Cat" + i;
            objCat.Breed = "Cat";
            objAnimals.Add(objCat);
        }
        else
        {
            IAnimal objDog = new Dog();
            objDog.Name = "Dog" + i;
            objDog.Breed = "Dog";
            objAnimals.Add(objDog);
        }
    }

    return objAnimals;
}
```

`IAnimal` interface has two properties and same properties are implemented in `Dog` and `Cat` class:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Breed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the grid view code please. Are you auto generating columns? Do `cat` and `dog` have exactly the same public properties?

Comment: Thanks @JonP for touching the right chord. Setting AutoGeneratedColumns property of GridView to false resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs when binding to a collection where the items in the collection are not all of the same type. The problem stems from the fact that rather than looking at the collection's type parameter, (`IAnimal` in your case), it instead uses the first element of the data source to determine the type of all the items in the collection, as a result, if your data source has items of different types, even if they all derive from a common base or have an identical set of properties, you'll still get this exception (unless you're lucky, and the items that aren't of the same type as the first item are all of types derived from it).

A possible solution is to create a wrapper (say, `AnimalWrapper`) that wraps the individual `Dog` and `Cat` instances, and exposes the properties you need to display in the grid, and then bind to a `List<AnimalWrapper>` instead.